# Rotate images in animations

Tags: landscape, animate

i tried to have the animations in landscape but failed.

please click below

http://www.twd-wind.com/inflowrc.pdf

you will see the first page the text is in landscape page, the second page the page layout is landscape but the graphics are not.

following is the tex code i used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[%
  pdftitle={},%
  pdfauthor={},%
  pdfsubject={},%
  pdfcreator={},%
  pdfproducer={},%
  pdfstartview=Fit,%
  bookmarks=false,%
  pdfkeywords={}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
Sample Test\\
\makebox[\textwidth]{\animategraphics[controls,timeline=timeline_R.txt]{1}{inflow}{1}{5}}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

any ideas to have the graphics also in landscape and the animation control below it????

thanks in advance. graham

Comment: The reason is probably that the page is too large. Thus it ships it out on the following page, which is not in landscape. Try shrinken your images and try again.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: I would suggest you to change your question title to "Rotate images in animations", it is more reflecting the question. Thus other people can more easily find the question and answer. :)

Comment: sorry for all the inconvenience. i have changed the title and put the file back so the link should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so what I said in the comments was to limit the size of the images... Which basically solves your problems.

You have to consider the `animategraphics` command as the equivalent of an `includegraphics` command. Thus it will simply insert the frame with the equivalent size of the image information etc.

So the solution is to do (you dont need the makebox):

```
\animategraphics[controls,width=0.9\textwidth,timeline=timeline_R.txt]{1}{inflow}{1}{5}
```

That is if your images have the perfect aspect ratio to fit on the landscape page. Otherwise try:

```
\animategraphics[controls,width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight,timeline=timeline_R.txt]{1}{inflow}{1}{5}
```

Which should work but not necessarily maintain aspect ratio.

#### Explicit rotation of images

When creating images which needs rotation, the usage of animate becomes a little more explicit. You then need an explicit loop and include the rotation in the definition. This also has the advantage of allowing more control for the user (as you can add whatever you want to the image).

So the result is this:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
Sample Test\\
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{1}%
  \multiframe{5}{ii=1+1}{%
      % ii = 1, 2, ..., 5
      \includegraphics[height=.5\textheight,angle=90]{inflow\ii.pdf}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions. i tried all of them including shrinking the image size but still the graphics are not in landscape. pls click here to see the original graphics and let me know if there is something wrong with this.

Comment: pls click below link to download the result file and also the original graphics. please let me know if there is anything wrong. thanks.  http://www.twd-wind.com/inflow.zip

Comment: the images are not in landscape as the document is already rotated. The pdf contain information about its rotation. This means a new way of using animate. See the updated answer.

Comment: i got it work ! great ! thanks a lot. one final question is the animation control underneath the image, that is not in landscape, can i rotate that too? at the playback arrows are pointing up and down. please download twd-wind.com/inflowrcx.pdf to have a look. graham

Comment: please let me know if there is a way to rotate the animation control button too.

Comment: That is more difficult. The button is a JavaScript drawn button directly parsed by the Reader. And as such you need to figure out the different tags for the different figures. Look into this, if it really matters. Otherwise please click that I have solved your problem by pushing the checkmark and (if you will) upvote the answer. Regards...

Comment: ok thanks for the hint. i push the check mark now. thanks for all the advice again.

Comment: @zeroth : Finally, `animate` and `pdfbase` (from `media9`) have been updated to support landscape pages with button faces and animation frames properly rotated.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

As of version `[2017/01/09]`, `animate`-generated animations can be placed on landscape pages, that is, inside the `landscape` environment provided by the `lscape` and `pdflscape` packages. Animation frames and control button faces are properly rotated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{animate}[2017/01/09]

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{10}
  \multiframe{101}{i=0+1}{\Huge\framebox[2em][r]{\i}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great Alex! Good job!